# Take text from large string

Tags: javascript

I have used ajax to get a large chunk of text which is the whole website html.
Now I need to grab specific divs in this text.
How can I grab a div and display only its text?
I have already tried .match and .search methods, just cannot understand how it really works.
I am also using xampp in localhost, windows 10.

Comment: Have you try jQuery? It makes thing like this super easy, otherwise, selecting specific div and filter out html codes is too tedious.

Comment: I am using jQuery, just don't know to get specific text.

Comment: Please show us the code you are using.

Comment: *How can I grab a div and display only its text?* Don't the `<div>`s have ids, classes, other attributes? You can use one of many jQuery selectors to get them.

Comment: This question is off-topic here. Just search "jquery get text from html" on Google to get tons of results (also from SO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `html` string to `jQuery()`, use `.find()` to get element having specific attributes, chain `.text()` to get `.textContent` of matched element

```js
var htmlStr = `<div>text<div class="specific">text</div></div>`;
    
var text = $(htmlStr).find(".specific").text();

console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: I have this line of code: `$(x.responseText).find(".tab-item-title").text()`. Now it grabs all the divs, but I want them separated. This won't work for me. How can I separated all those divs? There are maybe 30-50 divs that I need to separated with a new line.

Comment: Never mind, I found it. Just needed to add replace. Thanks! :)